# No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier when using htmlunit in Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, htmlunit

I am using htmlunit 2.36.0 in my Android Studio Project. I successfully compiled the apk but I am getting some runtime errors when I try to get a webpage.
Before, I was getting the following error:

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site
```

But I was able to fix the issue by adding this in the gradle:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

However, now I am facing another error:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:151)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.httpclient.HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.buildSSLSocketFactory(HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:89)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.configureHttpsScheme(HttpWebConnection.java:635)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.createHttpClientBuilder(HttpWebConnection.java:558)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getHttpClientBuilder(HttpWebConnection.java:519)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:171)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1407)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1326)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:396)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:317)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:469)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:450)
```

Apparently, there is no static field instance of AllowAllHostnameVerifier in its own class or or its superclasses. I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [hc.apache.org](https://hc.apache.org) documented:

`AllowAllHostnameVerifier` Deprecated. (`4.4`) Use `NoopHostnameVerifier`

If you  downgrade dependencies's version to `4.3`(2013~2015) exception will be resolved.

```
implementation 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.15'
```

Comment: @DeborahAnn The main problem is htmlunit. htmlunit 2.36.0 removed AllowAllHostnameVerifier

Comment: @DeborahAnn you can not use  htmlunit 2.36.0  for lower versions of httpclient

Comment: Can we talk in chat?

Comment: By the way, it works only with `implementation 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.14'`. No need for the httpcomponents.
I forgot to ask you something. Have you had the chance to try other versions below 2.36.0? Is 2.14 the only one to circumvent the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use the port for android:

https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android

Use this as the dependency:

```
implementation("net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-android:2.63.0")
```